# how to update a data in nested object

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to update a data in nested object using mongoose. My model is this:

```js
{
  _id: 123,
  shoppingCart: [{
    _id: 321,
    totalPrice: 110,
    itemCount: 1,
    items: [{
      title: "product123",
      quantity: 2
    }]
  }]
}
```

I want to update shoppingCart's items' quantity. I read the documents but I couldn't understand how can I update quantity?

Comment: Disregarding mongoose for a second, changing that quantity can be done like `obj.shoppingCart[0].items[0].quantity = 3;`. That looks like a populated db result though, so I don't think that's the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case your data is **not populated** (the doc you shared is saved in one collection):

As far as I can remember, there is no straight way to do this. You should get the doc first, and then update it as you want. The items are nested, so they each will also have an id:

```
const doc = await Model.findById(docId); // or find or findOne
const item = doc.shoppingCart.items.id(itemId);
item.quantity = 10;
await doc.save();
```

If you want to remove a sub document by title but don't have the itemId, you would have to search through items and find the id of that item, get the sub doc as before, do `item.remove()` and then `doc.save()`:

```
const items = doc.shoppingCart[0].items;
const idx = items.findIndex((item) => item.title === 'product123');
const item = items.id(items[idx]._id);
item.remove();
doc.save();
```

It's better to share what you have done so far. Then also share the Model, the shopping cart is shown as an array, which does not make sense I think.

By the way, mongoose has great documentation which is your good friend:
[Subdocument documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html)

Comment: What if I wanted to remove an item what I had to do. For example if I want to delete a product titled "product123" what code should I write?

Answer (score 0):

You want to use [arrayFilters](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/) like so:

```
db.collection.updateOne(
    {  
        //query to match document
    },
    { $inc: { "shoppingCart.items.$[element].quantity": 1 } }, //increase by one.
    { arrayFilters: [ { "element.title": "product123" } ] }
)
```